# React Context does not update with state

Tags: reactjs, state, react-state

I have code as such;

```
const ToastContextProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState<ToastDefinition[]>([]);

  const addToast = useCallback(
    (toast: ToastDefinition) => {
      if (toasts.find(({ id }) => id === toast.id)) {
        return logger.warn('Attempted to add a new toast with a duplicate ID!', {
          toast,
        });
      }

      setToasts((toasts) => [...toasts, { ...toast }]);
    },
    [toasts]
  );

  const removeToast = (id: string) => {
    setToasts((toasts) => toasts.filter((toast) => toast.id !== id));
  };

  const value = {
    addToast,
    removeToast,
  };

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={value}>
      <ToastPortal toasts={toasts} />
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

The idea is that I would call addToast in a component, where toast is an object like so;

```
{
    id: 'test',
    message: 'Hello world',
}
```

And if the **ID** exists within the toasts state, it will not be allowed. However, calling **console.log(toasts)** within **addToast** always logs an empty array, and the **arr.find()** check always returns undefined as a result, allowing duplicate toasts to be added.

The **ToastPortal** however, does receive the updated state value.

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-architecture-8tiv5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `addToast` to your `useEffect`'s dependency array so that the latest `addToast` function which closes over current `toasts` value takes part in your interval logic. An empty dependency array meant that the `addToast` that got created in the beginning was being repeatedly called and that method closed over initial value of `toasts` which was `[]`.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      addToast({
        id: "test",
        msg: "testmsg"
      });
    }, 5000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [addToast]);
```